# Corner test case scenario in subtraction

Tags: python, function, oop, math, pytest

I am learning OOP concepts in python. I came across a challenge where we are required to create an object 'comp' to perform the addition and subtraction of complex numbers. But I get 2 corner case test scenarios that fail for the code I have written.

```
class comp:

def __init__(self, Real, Imaginary=0.0):

    self.Real = Real
    self.Imaginary = Imaginary
    
def add(self,other):
    a=self.Real
    b=self.Imaginary
    c=other.Real
    d=other.Imaginary
    rsum=(a+c)
    isum=(b+d)
    print('Sum of the two Complex numbers :{}+{}i'.format(rsum,isum))
    #logging.debug('Sum of the two Complex numbers :{}+{}i'.format(rsum,isum))
    return('Sum of the two Complex numbers :{}+{}i'.format(rsum,isum))
    

def sub(self,other):
    a=self.Real
    b=self.Imaginary
    c=other.Real
    d=other.Imaginary
    rsub=(a-c)
    isub=(b-d)
    print('Subtraction of the two Complex numbers :{}+{}i'.format((rsub),(isub)))
    return('Subtraction of the two Complex numbers :{}+{}i'.format((rsub),(isub)))
```

The 2 failed outputs are:

1. Sum of the two Complex numbers :4+6i

Subtraction of the two Complex numbers :-2+-2i

2)Sum of the two Complex numbers :6+9i

Subtraction of the two Complex numbers :-6+-9i

I am unable to find how to make the code handle all the corner case scenarios. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are these corner cases? Should the expected output have a "-"  instead of a plus when the imaginary part is negative?

Comment: I think so. The expected output should only have one sign in the imaginary part. Its understandable when the real part is negative and code handles that I guess. But the imaginary part is taking the negative sign in literal and isn't multiplying it with the + sign in the standard form. So 2 signs are being shown, I cant think of a way to get the output handle the sign conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to convert the signs by reading through the built-in types documentation and other answers in StackOverflow.
Working code which covers the corner scenarios:

```
class comp:

def __init__(self, Real, Imaginary=0.0):

    self.Real = Real
    self.Imaginary = Imaginary
    
def add(self,other):
    a=self.Real
    b=self.Imaginary
    c=other.Real
    d=other.Imaginary
    rsum=(a+c)
    isum=(b+d)
    
    print('Sum of the two Complex numbers :%d+%di' % (rsum,isum))
    return('Sum of the two Complex numbers :%d+%di' % (rsum,isum ))
    #return (rsum+isum)

def sub(self,other):
    a=self.Real
    b=self.Imaginary
    c=other.Real
    d=other.Imaginary
    rsub=((a)-(c))
    isub=((b)-(d))
    
    print('Subtraction of the two Complex numbers :%d%+di' % (rsub,+(isub)))
    return('Subtraction of the two Complex numbers :%d%+di' % (rsub,+(isub)))
```